# PHP E-Commerce Multi-store engine

Tags: php, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I need advice with e-commerce engine which will allow create multisite internet-shops.
(When client have several shop in his e-commerce net)

With such functionality:

1. Shops have same design templates
2. Each shops which of them have own administrator, who can fill his
   shop separately with content.
3. Gloabal admin can give\stop rights to admins of shops
4. Users have single registration in the sistem, so being registered in
   one shop, you can use this login in any of them.

I have experience with ShopCart and VamShop (russian osCommerce fork), but both of them have single shop functions, and if I will setup several copies of them, I can solve tasks 1 and 2, but will meet problems with 3 and 4.

What solution\aproach can you advice for me?

PS: It's important, that it must be PHP-based engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PrestaShop 1.5 will soon be released.

As you can see on the roadmap, the last missed feature is the Multi-store management.

http://www.prestashop.com/en/milestones-1-5

> Multi-store management: With options for multiple currencies, multiple languages and multiple domains, multi-store management will be complete, efficient and integrated into PrestaShop. Multi-store will allow any merchant, regardless of its size to manage multiple stores from a single Back Office.

So i suggest you to stay tuned.

P.S.: An alternative is, however, Magento.

**EDIT: Prestashop 1.5 final version has been released: [DOWNLOAD](http://www.prestashop.com/en/download)**

Comment: Thank you! It's nice info for me, because I plan to use PrestaShop in my other projects, so it would be realy great if it will be able to solve multishop tasks as well!

Comment: I accepted this unswer, because I have plans on using PrestaShop for some other projects, and the information, that soon this engine will allow multi-store support was very usefull for me. And I knew befor about Magento, which was adviced bellow.

Comment: Prestashop 1.5 RC1 with Multi-store management has been released http://www.prestashop.com/en/milestones-1-5

Comment: Prestashop 1.5 final version was released today: http://www.prestashop.com/en/download

Answer (score 2):

You may try [PHPMall](http://www.netartmedia.net/mall/index.html) and [Kodemall](http://www.kodemall.com/). Both of them supports multi-vendor features, and bot of them are not cheap. I purchased PHPMall last year, and I personally didn't like the codes was constructed (not MVC, and many deprecated functions). It is working though, I just found it hard to modify because of the "dirty" programming style so I decided to create my own. I haven't tried Kodemall, which is based on OpenCart ecommerce script.

Comment: Thanks for your unswer. Kodemall is very expensive. PHPMall price looks more real, and thanks for your comments about problems you met with it!

Answer (score 2):

Magento will be a good choice to solve your problem.

For its community version, requirement 1 and 4 is already there. And an extension installed will easily give you the solution for 2 and 3.

And its enterprise version and professional version will contain these functions but charges for license per year.

Comment: I have hear about Magento, but as far as I see it's very heavy engine and worry it will be quite tricky to setup it. Any other to look at?

Comment: Not heavy if run on nginx with php-fpm. Yes, isn't easy to theme, so get a generic theme and try not to tweak much.